# How to bind to the context object JS

Tags: javascript

I want to bind ID to function's context object without overriding that context.

**setItemClickHandler** is a callback method. It already has context object and a property attached to it **this.index**.

My question is: How can I bind id property to that context so that I have **this.index** and **this.id**?

Noted: .bind() method override the existing context.

```
itemClickHandler = function (id) {
    events = {
        itemClick: setItemClickHandler
    };
}
setItemClickHandler = function () {
    this.index
    this.id ????
}
```

Comment: Add more code/example of usage.

Comment: Its just a simple function using its reference in multiple places and I want to pass id to it whenever I use the reference.

Comment: It would be helpful if your showed how you prebind index to `setItemClickHandler`.

Comment: It is called by library called HighCharts. That library bind properties to the context [this.index, this.isVisible, this.name]. I do not know how they bind or call that method its a blackbox to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overcame this issue with **Currying** concept

```
itemClickHandler = function (id) {
    events = {
        itemClick: setItemClickHandler(id)
    };
}
setItemClickHandler = function (id) {

    return function() {
        id
        this.index            
    }
}
```